# Knitting of Rmarkdown document fails because of code that checks for packages and installs them if they're missing. Why and what can I do?

Tags: r, r-markdown

First question here so I hope I did everything correctly.

I am using

```
if (!require(package)) install.packages('package')
library(package)
```

at the top of my Rmarkdown document to check if a package is installed, and if not, install it, and then of course load it. For some reason, the presence of the first line of code prevents my document from being knitted, with the following error:

```
[...]
 * 0x57adc60    0x41a98d3 C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x3da98d3
 * 0x57adc68    0x4280a19 C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x3e80a19

   ... (maximum recursion depth reached.)

Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 11
```

I have tested it by removing only the `if (!require...` lines from the document, I am sure they are the only culprits. Does anyone have any idea why, and has any code alternatives that do the same job while allowing me to knit my document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to package being a vector, what do you get if you replace those lines with something along the following ?

```
pkg_vec <- c("naniar", "pander")

for (pkg in pkg_vec){
        if (!require(package = pkg, character.only = TRUE))
        {
                install.packages(pkgs = pkg, character.only = TRUE)}
        library(pkg, character.only = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! The document knits and it looks like everything runs as it should! Doesn't look as nice, of course, but the important thing is that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more concise way to do what you're asking:

```r
packages <- c(...)
to_install <- setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages()))
install.packages(to_install, character.only = TRUE)
invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))
```